# How to use @bind (not @bind-Property) or bind on DOM property for custom elements in Blazor?

Tags: html, .net, blazor, web-component, blazor-webassembly

I have a custom element (`MdTextField` that renders Material Web's `<md-filled-text-field>`) that acts similar to `<input />`. Now the problem is, when using `@bind-Value`, what Blazor does is setting its `value` HTML **attribute** and not element (DOM) property. This does not work for the following case (please note I use `input` here to demonstrate the behavior, the custom component acts exactly like this standard `input`):

- An input value is not updated when its `value` **attribute** is updated, for example: `input.setAttribute("value", "new value");`. This happen after the input value is changed by users.
- Its value is changed if its property is set programmatically, for example: `input.value = "new value"`.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("input").setAttribute("value", "");
});

document.querySelector(".btn2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("input").value = "";
});
```

```html
<p>Edit the input below and try the buttons</p>

<input value="123" />
<button class="btn1">Clear value</button>
<button class="btn2">Correctly clear value</button>
```

Update: I just realized simply changing the value of the `input` and then click the button and it would not work at all. Basically the button doesn't work if the `input` was changed.

Here, when you click the Clear button, it works once, then if you change the `<input>` again, the `value` attribute doesn't change so if you click the button the 2nd time it doesn't work anymore. In fact, the value is of the `input` is still the value that user entered.

In Javascript, I can simply use `txt.value = ""` but it's not simple in Blazor.

I can solve the issue if I can do either of these:

- Somehow use `@bind="variable"` in Blazor for <del>`MdTextField`</del> `<md-filled-text-field>` or any custom tag like how it is working for standard `input`.
- Tell Blazor that `@bind-Value` should set the `value` **property** and not attribute, similar to [Lit's Property Expressions](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions):

  ```
  html`<my-list .listItems=${this.items}></my-list>`;
  ```

I know if all else fails, I can use Javascript to solve the problem but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

---

Here's an example component:

```
@* MyTextField.razor *@

@* Following HH's answer: *@
<md-filled-text-field @bind-value="Value" @bind-value:event="onchange" @bind-value:after="OnAfterValueChanged">
    @(ChildContent)
</md-filled-text-field>

@* My original code: *@
<md-filled-text-field value="@(Value)" @onchange="OnValueChanged">
    @(ChildContent)
</md-filled-text-field>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public string Value { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value?.ToString() ?? "");
    }

    async Task OnAfterValueChanged()
    {
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
@page "/test"

<MyTextField @bind-Value="text" />

<button @onclick="@(() => text = "")">Clear</button>

@code {

    string text = "123";

}
```

Here's a GitHub repository with the reproducible problem and the `md-filled-text-field` setup: https://github.com/datvm/BlazorCustomElementValueBinding

[image]

Comment: If @HH's answer works then ignore this.  I'm blanking on "what Blazor does is setting its value attribute and not property" [probably a senior moment by me].  Can you define what the `property` is?  Perhaps a bit more code?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis if what HH's answer does what I think it does then it's probably the solution. Sorry I used the wrong word there. By attribute I meant, it sets HTML attribute (likely using `el.setAttribute("value", value)`). Instead I want Blazor to set element DOM property (`el.value = value`). I hope this clears things up.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis the solution proposed by HH doesn't work. It acts the same as `value="@(Value)"` and the value property doesn't change, only the attribute does. I have also edited the HTML snippet above to demonstrate what Blazor is doing and what should be done/what I want instead.

Comment: Well, I'm still confused by this attribute/property thing too.

Comment: But a) your component shuld not assign to its own Value parameter and b) the code in the "HH's answer" part does not call ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(newValue); and thus will not update the parent.

Comment: @ℍℍ Thanks I updated the code following your latest comment. I am sorry I really tried to explain the attribute vs property thing, I added 2 bullet points but I am not sure if I can explain it more clearly. Basically attribute is the HTML attribute (`<tag-name your-attribute="attr-value" />`) while property is the actual element property (not accessible from HTML).

Comment: I think this clears it up a little: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003819/60761

Comment: @ℍℍ Yes that is correct! And as stated in that answer, `value` is not _reflected_ through `value` attribute. That's why I need Blazor to set its property instead of attributes.

Comment: @LukeVo - OK, I understand the attribute/property issue.  Are you saying that `<md-filled-text-field>` doesn't behave like `<input>`?  If so then that may be the Material Design JS modifying the DOM outside of Blazor.  As I'm no Material Design expert and don't know how to do an "install" to get to try and use them  in Blazor I can offer no further help.

Comment: One last thought.  If  `<md-filled-text-field>` is effectively an `<input>` then you should be using `@bind=@value`, not `@bind-Value`.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis No, it _behaves_ like `input` (which it should). You are correct if I could use `@bind=@value` for it. unfortunately it doesn't. If I put `<md-filled-text-field @bind="@Value">`, I receive a **runtime** error: `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@bind' is not a valid attribute name.`

Comment: Based on that error, I think the Razor compiler isn't compiling the `@bind` directive correctly because it doesn't believe `<md-filled-text-field>` in a input field.  I need to think about this: my guess is we need to write stuff directly as `RenderTreeBuilder` code.  It's getting late here: I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed if the web component had something like:

```
 attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
     if (name == "value" && oldValue !== newValue) {
         this.element.value = newValue;
         // this.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); //It may be necessary
     } 
 }
```

Since it doesn't have it, you have to create an Observer for that attribute using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Then, a javascript is necessary ("Observer.js")

```
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "value") {
            mutation.target.value = mutation.target.getAttribute("value");
        }
    }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
export const Observer = (targetNode) => observer.observe(targetNode, { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false });
export const UnObserver = () => observer.disconnect();
```

And then you can wrap everything in a Blazor component

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<md-filled-text-field 
    @ref="textfield" 
    value="@Value"
    @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs e) =>ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value?.ToString() ?? ""))"
    @attributes="Attributes">
</md-filled-text-field>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

    private IJSObjectReference? jsModule;
    private ElementReference textfield;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            jsModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Observer.js");
            await jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("Observer", textfield);
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() => await jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("UnObserver");

}
```

Comment: Yes unfortunately JS is needed in that case. However you don't actually need an observer if you can use JS. You can rely on `change` or `input` event for getting value and use JS to set its `value` property.

Comment: Doing it with Observer gives you 2 advantages: (1) You can observe other attributes without further code and (2) You can create a global Observer that observes the entire page and makes the changes to all Material components (without IJSRuntime) and it would be a code very similar to the one I put in the response

Answer (score 0):

Not final, but.  My `my-input` [a quick and dirty mock for `md-filled-text-field`] isn't working like it should, probably reflecting my rudimentary JS coding skills.  Perhaps someone reading this will help me out?

What it demonstrates is how to assign stuff in C# rather than Razor markup.  It compiles and runs!

It's in DotNet 8.

My `App` which adds the custom element.

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SO77583025.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script>
        class MyInput extends HTMLInputElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
            }
            // Element functionality written in here
        }

        customElements.define("my-input", MyInput);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And then my `Home`:

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@CustomInput("input")

@CustomInput("my-input")

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Reset">Reset</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Value : @_value</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string? _value;

    private RenderFragment<string> CustomInput => tag => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(5, tag);
        builder.AddAttribute(6, "class", "form-control mb-3");
        builder.AddAttribute(7, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(_value));
        builder.AddAttribute(8, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(this, __value => _value = __value, _value!));
        builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
        builder.CloseElement();
    };

    private void Reset()
        => _value = null;

}
```

Comment: Interestingly your code works for `input` but not _my_ custom element. Even more interesting, if the tag is `input`, no attribute is printed but if it's `md-filled-text-field`, Blazor prints `value` HTML attribute instead. I think Blazor is having special treatment for `input` here. I will make a Github repo with reproducible code soon and you can play around with it.

Comment: Here's the repository with the your suggested solution and the element setup already: https://github.com/datvm/BlazorCustomElementValueBinding

Comment: Will do.  [I'm working on another very intriguing question just above yours on WASM multithreading]  I like these non RTFM questions!

Comment: `md-filled-field` isn't quite what it seems.  It's a wrapper for an input field with widgets like icons,... Take a look at what happens in Developer tools in the browser when the value is changed.  I don't have an answer to this.

Comment: Yes, it does but the `input` is inside a Shadow DOM so it should not matter. From our perspective, we should not need to care what's in there. What I need is to change the `value` DOM property (instead of HTML attribute). So right now it's not possible without Javascript I guess. I have posted a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52500) and hopefully it will be granted.